# TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function, when trying to open() file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I wrote the following code which extracts the info. of a file and orders it alphabetically based on its second column objects:

```
import csv
import operator
import sys

def re_sort(in_file='books.csv', out_file='books_sort.csv'):
    data = csv.reader(open('books.csv', newline=''), delimiter=',')
    header = next(data)
    sortedlist = sorted(data, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    with open("books_sorted.csv", "w", newline='') as csvfile:
        cvsWriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        cvsWriter.writerow(header)
        cvsWriter.writerows(sortedlist)
```

Whenever I try to run this code on the command line, it gives me the error TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function. Do you guys see reasons why this may be happening. The following if a structured version of the contents in the file:

```
Title,            Author,        Publisher,  Year,  ISBN-10,   ISBN-13
Automate the...,  Al Sweigart,   No Sta...,  2015,  15932...,  978-15932...
Dive into Py...,  Mark Pilgr..., Apress,     2009,  14302...,  978-14302...
"Python Cook...,  "David Bea..., O'Reil...,  2013,  14493...,  978-14493...
Think Python...,  Allen B. D..., O'Reil...,  2015,  14919...,  978-14919...
"Fluent Pyth...,  Luciano Ra..., O'Reil...,  2015,  14919...,  978-14919...
```

Comment: This may be able to help you out: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811992/python3-csv-writer-failing-exiting-on-error-typeerror-newline-is-an-invalid?rq=1)

Comment: Please refer to a similar article on Stack Overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29840849/writing-a-csv-file-in-python-that-works-for-both-python-2-7-and-python-3-3-in

Comment: replace newline='\n' with lineterminator='\n'

Answer (score -3, accepted):

This may be able to help you out. It seems like that is an invalid variable name for what you are trying to do.

[The error occurs because newline="" is an invalid option for csv.writer(). Changing that should solve the problem. As seen here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32811992/python3-csv-writer-failing-exiting-on-error-typeerror-newline-is-an-invalid?rq=1)

Comment: This is essentially a link only answer. Please summarize the contents of the link.

Comment: The link contained the solution to my problem. Ny changing 'w' to 'wb' i was able to get rid of the newline altogether.

Comment: How does an answer that satisfied the asker get a down vote with no explanation?

Comment: if that question solves the problem, this one should be closed as a duplicate of the other, not as an answer pointing to the other one

Comment: @Tyler_P: because the OP's question was about inadvertently using Python 2's open(), not Python 3's csv writer, which is irrelevant here. (The asker is mistaken about the root-cause. It happens. )

Answer (score 26):

`open` built-in function got the `newline` keyword in python 3. Given that, I presume you're running your script using python 2.

In order to solve your issue:

1. make sure you have at least python v3.2 (https://docs.python.org/release/3.2/library/functions.html#open),
2. and run your program using the right python version, e.g. `python3 myscript.py`.