# Wrong Python version when ran as a child process in Node.js?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, child-process

Currently I am trying to run a Python script that responds with a string of HTML code, and I am running this through a Node.js child process. Here is the code I've written for the server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));

app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["graphing.py"]);
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("It worked!")
        res.write(data.toString());
        res.end();
    });
    pythonProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("ERROR!")
        console.log(data.toString());
        res.write("Error. Check console.");
        res.end();
    });
});
```

I have tried running this code with just simple print statements in Python, and that has worked perfectly fine. However, when I try it with my proper script, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "graphing.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(mpld3Plot("./data/weather/daily/Baka_ThruApr-2019.csv", ('maxTemp','minTemp')))  
  File "graphing.py", line 18, in mpld3Plot
    with open(abs_path, newline='') as csvfile:
TypeError: 'newline' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

After a bit of digging around, I am fairly certain that this issue is because the server is running the Python script in Python 2, as [apparently the newline parameter wasn't added until Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51833105/12883203). When I run the Python script on its own, it works perfectly fine. How would I go about getting the server to run the script in Python 3 specifically? Thanks.

Edit:
When I change the path from 'python' to the absolute path, I get this error:

```
events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn C:UsersNAMEAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython38python.exe ENOENT     
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:UsersNAMEAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython38python.exe',     
  path: 'C:UsersNAMEAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython38python.exe',
  spawnargs: [ 'graphing.py' ]
}
```

Any ideas as to what I should do now?

Comment: How do you set your Python env when you successfully execute your code? Unless you set your Python environment, it will take the default. What do you get if you execute ```python --version``` in a terminal? What do you get when you execute your code stand alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic problem when calling Python from other scripts, usually because the default environment that you are emersed in when running from the terminal is not the same as that which is present when you call an executable from within a program or script. Therefore replace:

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["graphing.py"]);
```

with:

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('/complete/path/to/python3',["graphing.py"]);
```

(In other words - specify the full path to the exact Python3 executable you want, rather than rely on the native environment at run-time).

Comment: I edited the post to show what happens when I do that. Any ideas past this? Thanks.

Comment: Please show the full path you actually used - the one in your error suggests it was "C:UsersNAMEAppDataLocalProgramsPythonPython38python.exe", which doesn't sound like it was inputted correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much. When I copied the path it came in the form 'path1\path2\path3', so it read it as "path1path2path3'. I just replaced the \'s with /'s, so it worked perfectly. Thanks so much.

Comment: Super! if it was helpful, would you mind marking it as a correct answer and upvoting it?